# ¿Cómo puedo darle formato a los números de un array?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos:

```
        const data = [
    {
    id: 0,
    Name: Juan,
    Amount: 1000,
},
{
    id: 1,
    Name: losh,
    Amount: 1000,
}
]
```

El hecho es que quiero darle formato con

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CO',{ style: 'currency', currency: 'COP' }).format()
```

Pero no encuentro una manera de modificar el array de objetos y que le de ese formato al Amount

Comment: El formato es algo propio de la presentación, no de la variable en si misma. Un mismo número puede estar almacenado como `1000` y pintarse como `1000`, `1.000` o `1,000`, pero siempre será el mismo número: `1000`

Comment: El hecho es que lo quiero mostrar como moneda y se muestre como $ 1.000,00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasta ahora vas muy bien, lo único que te falta es reasignar los datos.

Si lo que quieres es modificar parte del contenido de todos los objeto de un array, solamente necesitas usar la función `forEach` y reasignar la propiedad `Amount` de cada iteración.

```
data.forEach((el) => {

    el.Amount = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CO',{ style: 'currency', currency: 'COP' }).format(el.Amount)
  
});
```

Fíjate en el funcionamiento de este snippet.

```js
const data = [
    {
    id: 0,
        Name: "Juan",
        Amount: 1000,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        Name: "losh",
        Amount: 1000,
    }
];

console.log(data)

data.forEach((el) => {

    el.Amount = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CO',{ style: 'currency', currency: 'COP' }).format(el.Amount)
  
});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Y en el momento en que has reasignado `Amount` a un string con el símbolo has perdido la posibilidad de *operar* con ella. El formato de moneda se da al imprimir, no se debería de dar al dato en si mismo.

Comment: Y cómo sabes si el array de objetos que el usuario ha presentado es el resultado de realizar operaciones con la propiedad cantidad?? Él simplemente ha preguntado cómo transformar un número en un formato con símbolo de moneda.

Comment: No lo sé, pero sé que no se debe mezclar la presentación con la información. Son dos capas diferentes. Él simplemente pregunta una cosa, y yo simplemente indico otra... en ningún momento he dicho que esté mal la respuesta (de lo contrario, la habría votado negativamente... y no lo hice :) ), solo digo que no es buena práctica hacer eso. Es una aclaración nada más.